# Flutter Stepper how to show the selected value as the title of the previous step?

Tags: flutter

I would like to show the selected / entered value as the title of the step once the user clicks on "Continue". How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Step(
  title: const Text('Name'),
  isActive: true,
  subtitle: Text(nameVar),
  state: StepState.indexed,
  content: new TextFormField(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    autocorrect: false,
    onChanged: (String value) {
      setState(() {
        nameVar = value;
      });
    },
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
);
```

worked for me